# When does the ETS2 Polar Express challenge end?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

The blog doesn't say when it ends, and I would like to know until when do I have to complete the challenge to get the Raven skin DLC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new post appeared today on their blog (about ATS), at the bottom it has the following:

> Due to overwhelming community response and upcoming Holiday Season our team has decided to extend SCS Polar Express Holiday event past Christmas Eve and into the New Year - everyone who finishes their assigned delivery will receive the exclusive Raven Truck Design DLC!

Still not a real date, but now you at least have an idea about the remaining time.

**UPDATE**

Quoting from today's blogpost:

> Holiday Event will come to an end on Wednesday, January 14th 2015. If you are still in progress of trying to earn your exclusive Raven Truck Design DLC by completing it -  hurry up!

Comment: Awesome, it's good to know that i can still balance out work and still have time to get the skin, thank you!